# How can I fix my figure numbers when I delete an image in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

When I delete a captioned image in Word 2016 and then refresh the document using **CTRL + A** and **F9** it updates the captions, but they are incorrect and give me duplicate figure numbers.

This is before deleting an image

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/852f768be9dcdd674962252f991eb3ab.png]

This is after deleting image 2, and pressing **CTRL+A F9**

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/49038a516194fdc39b3bdf23487f990d.png]

As you can see image 2 is gone, but there are now duplicate Figure 3 which is going to be a massive pain as the document grows.

How can I fix this and safely delete images without corrupting the figure numbers? All of the figures are generated by Word and I have not generated any myself.

Comment: Get them in the right order? Why would your Document start with Figure 3/4 and not 1? At least that what it currently looks like and which might be part of the problem.

Comment: I don't know? This is what word has done. All I have been doing is adding captions and updating them. How do I re-order them without removing and re-adding the images.